# rqt_plot: PyQt4 and PyQt5 wrapping same object class

Tags: python, qt, ros

I am trying to use the `rqt_plot` feature of ROS and every time I call `rqt_plot` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rqt_plot", line 6, in <module>
    from rqt_plot.plot import Plot
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .data_plot import DataPlot
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .pyqtgraph_data_plot import PyQtGraphDataPlot
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/pyqtgraph_data_plot.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pyqtgraph import __version__ as pyqtgraph_version
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .Qt import QtGui
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/Qt.py", line 104, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore and PyQt5.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class
```

I've seen other people fix this by uninstalling Qt4 and only using Qt5, but I'm not entirely sure why this problem exists for me because I do not believe I even have qt4 installed.

Calling `pip3 uninstall pyqt4` returns:

```
Cannot uninstall requirement pyqt4, not installed
```

How can i force `rqt_plot` to use qt5 or what else should I do?

This is with ROS kinetic and ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You might have Qt4 installed, to be sure check by opening python from commandline and running:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
print(QT_VERSION_STR)
```

Similarly you can check for Qt5 by replacing 4 with 5.  However, you will need to exit and restart python first.

Comment: So apparently I have QT4.8.7 installed unbeknownst to pip. How would I go about removing it? Or should I remove qt5 instead?

Comment: Can you share your PYTHONPATH, you can check it by running `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: /home/morten/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: Can you try to just keep the ROS package in the PYTHONPATH by running `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` this could point us if there is conflict against something in your catkin_ws.

Comment: After running the `export` command followed by `rqt_plot` I get the same QT version error again